# USB To Serial under OpenSuse 11.3

Tags: linux, opensuse, tty

I have a LogiLink USB-To-Serial adapter. This has the PL2303 chip inside. When I insert the device:

```
[26064.927083] usb 7-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 9
[26065.076090] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[26065.076099] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[26065.076105] usb 7-1: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[26065.076110] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[26065.079181] pl2303 7-1:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[26065.091296] usb 7-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

So the device is recognized and the converter is attached to ttyUSB0.
When I do screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 I get the error:

```
bash: /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied
```

So I went looking in the file permissions. ls -l from the /dev folder reports:

```
crw-rw----  1 root dialout 188,   0 2011-04-26 15:47 ttyUSB0
```

I added my user lars to the dialout group. When I use the commands groups under lars it shows that I'm in the group. Though I still recieve the permissions denied error, as lars, and as root.

I'm trying to connect to a console cable to configure some Cisco switches. My OS is OpenSuse 11.3 x86_64 with kernel version 2.6.34.7-0.7-desktop.

Comment: did you logout and log back in after the group add?

Comment: Yes I did. I logged out. When that didn't help I rebooted. Still the same error.

Comment: Don't know about SUSE, but when I get a weird permissions issue on Redhat I check selinux.

Comment: I'm not running SELinux

Answer (score 1):

First, verify your config and access:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
kill = ^H; min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -echo
```

Now configure them in a `safer` mode:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 sane
```

and

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
```

now, if `screen` won't work, you could try `minicom` or `cu`. I like `cu`, small and efficient, it use your tty as terminal, like `ssh` you could end a session by hitting `~.` or send a break with `~#`.

```
cu -l ttyUSB0
```

(notice that there is no `/dev/` ;)

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the possibility that this might be a 'screen' issue, try:

setserial -a /dev/ttyS0

to check for access permission, and then see if you can communicate using 'minicom'.